# Google App Script not accessible even though published as public

Tags: google-apps-script

Not sure what I'm missing here. I deployed a google apps script as a web-app with the below options from the menu option in the script editor

Execute the App as : User accessing the app
Who has access to the app: Anyone

Yet, when I tried to access the URL, anonymously, it asked me to log-in and when I did from another account, I keep getting the below error
You need permission to access this item.

You are signed in as ******@gmail.com, but you don't have permission to access this item. You can request access from the owner or choose a different account. Learn more

Request access   Choose a different account

What I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

checked further, when i write the restriction parameter on the Service Class to the log, it is reading as MYSELF, even though in the menu option the app is deployed with the "Anyone" option.

Comment: just a silly question: are you trying to access the url ending in /exec and not the one ending in /dev, right?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem when creating a new script? Can you share your script code or even just the url? Some screenshots of this would also be good, as it's tough to believe :) since I can replicate it.

Comment: I guess @FaustoR. is right. You need to use the URL ending with exec. The one provided by the cloud upload icon.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the correct answers from the comment:

@FaustoR

> just a silly question: are you trying to access the url ending in /exec and not the one ending in /dev, right? – Fausto R. May 29 '13 at 22:10

@br-araujo

> I guess @FaustoR. is right. You need to use the URL ending with exec. The one provided by the cloud upload icon. – br araujo Jun 13 '13 at 14:58 
>   And to summarize:

Won't work: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/LATEST_APP_KEY/dev`

Will work : `https://script.google.com/macros/s/LATEST_APP_KEY/exec`